# Fourier coefficients for elliptic curves on average

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-forms

Fix a prime p, and look at elliptic curves in some family (e.g. all elliptic curves ordered by height). How often do the Fourier coefficients a_p occur? Are there any conjectures?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand the question, but is this what you mean?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sato%E2%80%93Tate_conjecture

Comment: In Sato-Tate you fix the curve and vary $p$. Ian wants to do the opposite.

Comment: Possibly related: Theorem 2 in Serre's "Répartition asymptotique des valeurs propres de l'operateur de Hecke $T_p$" (this is about the trace of $T_p$ on the space of _newforms_ $S_k(N)^{\mathrm{new}}$ when $k+N \to \infty$, so we can fix $k$ and let $N \to \infty$). We obtain a measure $\mu_p$ which is not the Sato--Tate measure! Elliptic curves over $\Bbb Q$ (ordered by _conductor_) correspond to Hecke newforms with _rational_ coefficients, so I am not sure what can be said exactly here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a very clear discussion of some results in this direction in section 1 of Lenstra's paper ["Factoring Integers with Elliptic Curves"](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1971363). I'll attempt to summarize.

There are finitely many (about $2p$) isomorphism classes elliptic curves over $\mathbb{F}_p$. Most sampling methods choose the isomorphism class of $E$ with probability $1/|\mathrm{Aut}(E)|$. For example (in characteristic not $2$ or $3$), suppose you pick $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ at random and generate the curve $y^2=x^3+ax+b$, discarding it if it is singular. Then the number of $(a,b)$ for which you will generate a curve isomorphic to $E$ is $(p-1)/|\mathrm{Aut}(E)|$. I imagine sampling by height will have the same effect.

Weighting by automorphism groups, the number of $E$ for which $a_p=t$ is $H(t^2-4p)$, where $H(D)$ is the Kronecker class number. For $t = 2 \alpha \sqrt{p}$ with $\alpha$ fixed and $<1$, we are looking at $H(-\Delta)$ for $\Delta = 4(1-\alpha^2) p$. $H(-\Delta)$ is $\Delta^{1/2+o(1)}$, but the oscillations are large enough to swamp the effect of $\alpha$.

In some moral sense, one wants to say that we are converging on the distribution propositional to $\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}$ as $p \to \infty$. In particular, it is true that the moments are approaching the moments of this semicircular distribution; see [Birch](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/cgi/reprint/s1-43/1/57).

Answer (score 6):

As others have mentioned, if $p$ is fixed then you're really looking at elliptic curves over a fixed finite field.

From some points of view an interesting variant would be to look at elliptic curves say $E_{a,b}:y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$ where $a$ and $b$ vary over integers in a box, say $|a| \leq A$ and $|b| \leq B$ and relatively small compared to $p$.  The one might try to find asymptotic results that hold as $p$, $A$, $B$ get large together.  If $A$ and $B$ aren't too big then this is giving more information about individual curves.  For example, in bounding the average analytic rank of elliptic curves it is important to get a good bound on $$\frac{1}{AB} \sum_{p < P} \sum_{|a| \leq A} \sum_{|b| \leq B} a_P(E_{a,b})$$ with $A$ and $B$ as small as possible.  For example, see A. Brumer, The average rank of elliptic curves. I, Invent. Math. 109(3), 445–472 (1992).

In a different but related direction, there is a paper of David and Pappalardi, [Average Frobenius distributions of elliptic curves](http://www.mathstat.concordia.ca/faculty/cdavid/publi.html) (it's the fourth from the bottom) on this subject.  They get a kind of Lang-Trotter on average, so they are varying both $p$ and the coefficients defining the elliptic curves.  Stephan Baier later made some improvements on this problem [here](http://www.faculty.iu-bremen.de/sbaier/papers/langtrotternew.pdf).

Comment: Wow, thanks! David's and Papalardi's paper seems to answer the question for a fixed prime, too (section 4). It's in term of the Kronecker class number, as David wrote above. 

Answer (score 2):

Wouter Castryck spoke about this at a GTEM workshop in Warwick. He considers isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over $\Bbb F_p$. His results are written up here:

http://wis.kuleuven.be/algebra/hubrechts/DistributionTraces.pdf

Of course there are a finite number of isomorphism classes of elliptic curves over a given finite field. So to answer your question for say elliptic curves over $\Bbb Q$ ordered by height, you would have to understand the distribution of the image of mod p reduction.

I hope this at least gives a start.